# Which trend has a better fit?

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I have a time series data with 2 trend lines plotted; the red implies polynomial trend fitting while the black line is obtained from lowess (locally weighted smoothing). I'm not sure which trend line I should pick as they seem pretty much similar to each other. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: They both seem quite off. But if I had to choose I would choose LO(W)ESS.

Comment: I'd say the black line is slightly better but neither of them are great. If you play with the lowess tuning parameter you will be able to get a vastly better fit. Try using the command `lowess(x, y, f = my_f_value)` try different values of `my_f_value` in $(0,1)$ plot the results. The default `f` is `2/3` --- I'd guess something like `0.2` might be better but you will need to experiment yourself here.

Comment: What do you intend to use this for? I would probably start by producing a seasonal decomposition instead (see `help("stl")`).

Comment: Also, why don't you just calculate the AIC and compare the model fits based on that?

Comment: @Roland Cannot use stl because it is data measured annually; I'll have a go at AIC

Comment: For what purpose are you 'picking' trendlines? I am asking because I see that you have second black line, it's a broken line. Why do you think that this third line isn't the best fit?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The broken line is the plot of the original data

Comment: Why don't you take that line as your fit?

Comment: The question about that broken line is a bit like a trick question. The point of it is that thinking about the answer makes you come up with a way to express what is and what is not a better fit. Without expressing the purpose of the fit there is no way to give an answer to the question which line is better.